# Is there a way to bulk-extract TV programme-descriptions, from WMC .WTV files?

Tags: windows, windows-media-center, audio-recording

I record quite a lot of radio and TV programmes off Windows Media Center and, using Karen's Powertools Directory Printer, list them off Win Explorer into a .txt file (and subsequently into a spreadsheet), by filename.

Many of the programmes have the same title but usually their own programme description. Karen's Directory Printer extracts many programme details, but not the programme description

Ideally, I would like to be able to select a stack of filenames in Windows Explorer and have the programme descriptions copied, via the usual .txt file or directly into a spreadsheet as a line of text.

(I've already tried contacting 'Joe Winett' joe@karenware.com but received no reply; and tried the Software Recommnedations SE)

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: I can share with you some VBScript which will output the metadata associated with a WTV file. From that you can see, amongst other things, the title and the description. Would that be useful?

Comment: Yes please, Richard - that would be most helpful. I assume you can post it here; otherwise please advise alternative route (email attachment?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is a script which will output the metadata for all of the WTV files in a folder. Put the following into notepad (or your text editor of choice) and save it as `extract-metadata.vbs`

```vbs
Option Explicit

Dim oShell : Set oShell  = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim oFSO : Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFolder : Set oFolder = oShell.Namespace(oFSO.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName))
Dim oFile, iPos, sHeader(999), sVal

' Get the names of each of the fields.

For iPos = 0 to 999
    sHeader(iPos) = oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFolder.Items, iPos)
Next

' For each file in the folder, get the data in that field and (assuming it's not
' empty) display it.

For Each oFile in oFolder.Items
    For iPos = 0 To 999
        sVal = oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFolder.ParseName(oFile.Name), iPos)
        If sVal <> "" Then WScript.Echo sHeader(iPos) & " (" & iPos & "): " & sVal
    Next
Next

Set oShell = Nothing
Set oFSO = Nothing
Set oFolder = Nothing
```

Open a command line, go to the folder containing your files and run this with:

```
cscript extract-metadata.vbs > output.txt
```

Open `output.txt` and you'll see something like this (note: not my recording!):

```
Name (0): The Only Way Is Essex_ITV2 +1_2011_09_25_23_12_00.wtv
Size (1): 721 MB
Item type (2): Windows Recorded TV Show
Date modified (3): 26/09/2011 09:17
Date created (4): 23/10/2011 18:17
Date accessed (5): 23/10/2011 18:17
Attributes (6): A
Perceived type (9): Video
Owner (10): Administrators
Kind (11): Recorded TV
Genre (16): Shows;Other Shows
Rating (19): Unrated
Title (21): The Only Way Is Essex
Length (27): 00:50:57
Protected (29): No
Computer (53): RICHARD-PC (this computer)
Filename (155): The Only Way Is Essex_ITV2 +1_2011_09_25_23_12_00.wtv
Shared (173): No
Folder name (176): Recorded TV
Folder path (177): C:\Users\Public\Recorded TV
Folder (178): Recorded TV (C:\Users\Public)
Path (180): C:\Users\Public\Recorded TV\The Only Way Is Essex_ITV2 +1_2011_09_25_23_12_00.wtv
Type (182): Windows Recorded TV Show
Link status (188): Unresolved
Date released (192): 0
Channel number (253): 27
Closed captioning (255): No
Rerun (256): No
SAP (257): No
Program description (259): New: Brand new series of the true life soap. It is Jess's 26th birthday party. Kirk has a new boy toy, and Mark's on a journey of self discovery and enlightenment. [S]
Recording time (260): ?25/?09/?2011 ??23:12
Station call sign (261): ITV2 +1
Station name (262): ITV2 +1
Sharing status (269): Not shared
```

As you can see, field `21` has the title and field `259` has the description. It's worth noting that if you recorded the show using Windows Media Center on Windows 8 then the description is in field `268` instead.

Hopefully that will give you a starter for 10 which will allow you to extract the recording data and populate a csv file for opening in a spreadsheet.

If you get stuck, then give me a shout and I'll try and help out.

Comment: That's amazing - thank you so much. So "Program description (259)" refers to WIN7? I've just got caught up with some domestic issues, so won't be free to concentrate on this for week or two, but will certainly do so when I've got some free time.

Comment: Also, tho' unrelated to the above, I saw on-screen yesterday that BBC is going HD-only (possible exception: BBC News channel). My EPG has always listed HD channels as "No data available" (my reception is Freeview off a TV antenna) so even tho' the Info channel 799 says "No changes needed" I expect to lose easy access to BBC and may have to set programmes manually.  ;-<

Comment: @iSeeker Yep, the example I gave is for Windows 7. EPG Collector can give you EPG data for the HD channels :)

Comment: Again, many thanks.

Comment: After much delay I finally got round to getting one-line Program Descriptions into my WMC file spreadsheet by setting iPOS to 0 and 259 in your code. As the Description can come as a number of sentences I needed to concatenate a number of OFFSETs to get them all on the one line - fiddly but got there in the end. Many thanks. (If I don't hear back from you, I might post it as an answered question, giving you full acknowledgement - I couldn't have done it without your code.)

Comment: @iSeeker Great to hear you got it sorted! Posting your code as an answered question would probably be the most helpful for everyone else :)

Comment: Glad I was able to make effective use of your advice, Richard. Not sure if many people still use WMC or even go so far as to copy out the Programme Descriptors, but I will post it "in due course" (just don't hold your breath waiting   ; - >  )